# typedef in Preprocessor macro

Tags: c++

I have a macro definition like this, to easily create a shared_ptr for a class:

```
#define create_ptr(__TYPE__) typedef std::shared_ptr<__TYPE__>
```

What I want to now is to append "Ptr" to the class name, so that

```
create_ptr(MyClass)
```

would result in a `typedef` named `MyClassPtr` as `std::shared_ptr<MyClass>`
How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Names starting with two low lines are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: Instead of using a macro why not use `auto`.  Then you could use `auto foo = make_shared<MyClass>(params_if_needed);`.  Now you don't have a macro and the object is initialized to a valid state upon creation.

Comment: @KerrekSB So I can't use `__TYPE__`? What else would I use instead of `__TYPE__`?

Comment: @defense2000x: Correct. You can use `TYPE`, though, or `T`.

Comment: thanks, didn't know that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need token concatenation `##`

```
#define create_ptr(__TYPE__) typedef std::shared_ptr<__TYPE__> __TYPE__ ## Ptr;

class Foo{
public:
};

create_ptr(Foo)

FooPtr foo;
```

For detailed explanation have a look here https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html

Answer (score 4):

An alternative route is a using declaration:

```
template <typename T>
using sp = std::shared_ptr<T>;

sp<int> my_shared_int_pointer ....
```